# vsCode refresh tree when adding new Item

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I use the following code to show tree items,

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/tree-view-sample

The items which is shown in the tree is related to a file, if the file changed the number of the tree items should be changed accordingly(using `createFileSystemWatcher` which works ok), currently I’ve add the code of the file watcher and when debug it stops there (on the `getChildren` function when I'm changing the file) and I see that I’ve provided the **new updated** entries (in the code),however the tree **doesn’t** refreshed with the new data, any idea what am I missing here ?  somehow the new updated data is not reflected in the tree. as I new to this topic maybe I miss something. if the code is OK and there is a bug or this is not supported please let me know.

```
export class TaskTreeDataProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<TreeItem> {

private _onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.EventEmitter<TreeItem | null> = new vscode.EventEmitter<TreeItem | null>();
  readonly onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.Event<TreeItem | null> = this
    ._onDidChangeTreeData.event;

  private eeake: Promise<TreeItem[]> | undefined = undefined;
  private autoRefresh: boolean = true;

  constructor(private context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    this.autoRefresh = vscode.workspace
      .getConfiguration(“sView")
      .get("autorefresh");

    let filePath = this.fileName;
    let fileWatcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(filePath);
    fileWatcher.onDidChange(() => (this.eeake = this.getChildren()), this.refresh());
  }

  refresh(): void {
    this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire();
  }

  public async getChildren(task?: TreeItem): Promise<TreeItem[]> {
    let tasks = await vscode.tasks
      .fetchTasks({ type: “run” })
      .then(function (value) {
        return value;
      });

    let entry: TreeItem[] = [];
    if (tasks.length !== 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
        entry[i] = new TreeItem(
          tasks[i].definition.type,
          tasks[i].name,
          {
            command: “sView.executeTask",
            title: "Execute",
            arguments: [tasks[i]]
          }
        );
      }
    }
    return entry;
  }

  getTreeItem(task: TreeItem): vscode.TreeItem {
    return task;
  }
}



class TreeItem extends vscode.TreeItem {
  type: string;
  constructor(
    type: string,
    label: string,
    collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState,
    command?: vscode.Command
  ) {
    super(label, collapsibleState);
    this.type = type;
    this.command = command;
    this.iconPath = getIcon();
  }

}
```

If there is something missing please let me know and I add, I'm really stuck with it.

If there is another way to refresh the tree please let me know

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it correctly from the question, but you're saying that "I see that I’ve provided the new updated entries (**in the code**)" - is `entry` contains the new updated item also in run time (if you put a breakpoint there)? Beside that everything looks good. I'm doing similar with my extension: https://github.com/moshfeu/vscode-compare-folders/blob/62096473af8ec7bd05e2ac8fc25d942bba1a47da/src/providers/foldersCompareProvider.ts#L119

Comment: @MoshFeu - thanks, yes exactly! in runtime (via debug), I see everything is updated , new entry provided/ deleted entry . however the tree doesnt reflect that, I see the entries from the beginning , any changed doesn't reflected in the tree. if you have any hint please let me know. thank you!

Comment: I don't see a reason for that. But (although it's not part of StackOverflow policy) if your repo is public (on Github or something) I can try to give a look, maybe something will jump.

Comment: `fileWatcher.onDidChange(() => (this.eeake = this.getChildren()), this.refresh());` this line looks suspicious to me. I believe you mean: `fileWatcher.onDidChange(() => { this.eeake = this.getChildren(); return this.refresh() });`

Comment: But your current code is actually passing the return value of `this.refresh()` as the **2nd arg** to `.onDidChange`, instead of being part of the callback listener.

Comment: @hackape - can you please write it as answer and i'll change my code accordingly and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last line in constructor looks suspicious to me.

```
fileWatcher.onDidChange(() => (this.eeake = this.getChildren()), this.refresh());
```

I believe you mean:

```
fileWatcher.onDidChange(() => {
  this.eeake = this.getChildren();
  this.refresh();
});
```

Your original code actually immediately invokes `this.refresh()` in constructor and pass the return value as the *2nd arg* to `fileWatcher.onDidChange()`. `this.refresh()` wasn't part of the listener passed as 1st arg to `onDidChange()`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I miss this part...as this is my first typescript project and vscode it will be great if you can provide a feedback on the rest of the code. thank you!

Comment: ^ Sorry, I'm not experienced w/ vscode extension. I can only help you catch this bug, not much I can comment about your code though.